# Select option value based on input value

Tags: javascript

I have a form selling lengths of cable, there is one price for lengths (5 - 95m) and a second for (100-200m). Based on the length put in the input field I would like the correct price option selected in the drop down menu. What javascript would I need for this.

```
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Price Option</option>
    <option value="5.83">5 to 95m - £5.83</option>
    <option value="5.00">100 to 200m - £5.83</option>
</select>

Length required:
<input type="number" id="length" size="4" maxlength="5" min="5" max="200" step="5">

<input type="button" value="Calculate">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take the blue one. Seriously, you should consider making at least one attempt and show us the result.

Comment: Probably the one you find on Google. If I only copy-paste your question title I get plenty of answers redirecting... (guess where)!

Answer (score 0):

I've added a function in my demo to calculate on change and on button click. Best of luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/vL1a4sdu/

```
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Price Option</option>
        <option value="5.83">5 to 95m - £5.83</option>
        <option value="5.00">100 to 200m - £5.83</option>
</select>

Length required:
<input type="number" id="length" size="4" maxlength="5" min="5" max="200" step="5">
<input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate">

<div id="cost"></div>

<script>

    $('#leaveCode').change(function(){
        var price = $(this).val();
        var length = $("#length").val();
        if ( length ) {
            var cost = calculate(price, length);
            $("#cost").text(cost);
        }
    });

    $('#calculate').click(function(){
        var price = $( "#leaveCode" ).val();
        var length = $("#length").val();
        if ( price !== null && length !== null ) {
            var cost = calculate(price, length);
            $("#cost").text(cost);
        }
    });

    function calculate(price,length) {
        var cost = price*length;
        return cost;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it this way

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Price Option</option>
<option value="5.83">5 to 95m - £5.83</option>
<option value="5.00">100 to 200m - £5.83</option>
</select>

Length required:
<input type="number" id="length" size="4" maxlength="5" min="5" max="200" step="5" onblur="quickSelect()">

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="quickSelect()">
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function quickSelect() {
      var len = Number($("#length").val());
    if (len >= 5 && len <= 95) {
           document.form.dropdown[1].selected = "1"
      }
      if (len >= 100 && len <= 200) {
           document.form.dropdown[2].selected = "1"
      }
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/mpv1e72j/ to solve this with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#length").change(function(){
        var len = Number($("#length").val());
        if (len >= 5 && len <= 95) $("#leaveCode").val("5.83");
        if (len >= 100 && len <= 200) $("#leaveCode").val("5.00");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks terrywb, instead of specifying actual values for #leaveCode is there a way to select the first or second option

Comment: @JCob, it looks like you found a solution below.  I imagine that you would also want to programmatically pull your range checks (max and min) out of your elements.